# Настройка форматтера Eclipse для форматирования цепочек вызовов

Tags: eclipse

В **Eclipse** настроен **форматтер** исходного кода.
Настроен не так, как мне нравится, а именно, если у меня есть цепочки вызовов, которые выглядят так:

[image: Исходный текст до запуска форматтера]

После обработки форматтером, вся цепочка выравнивается в одну строку, что отрицательно сказывается на читаемости кода:

[image: Текст после обработки форматттером]

Пока не нашел, как правильно настроить форматтер, единственное, что придумал - добавлять знаки однострочного комментария после каждой строки:

[image: Обманываем форматтер]

Вопрос, как настроить форматтер так, чтобы после его отработки исходный текст выглядел как на первом изображении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя версия (Linux):

> Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1) Build id: 20161007-1200

Следите за стрелками :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо